# OTA Device Skin Download Not Working Because Of NTLM Proxy

Tags: codenameone

Most of the time I am working behind a Microsoft NTLM Authenticationg Proxy. For some reason the proxy settings in the Simulator don't work with that.
Most java programs I get to work with the proxy through a program called cntlm, but not the Codename One Simulator or other Codename One features requiring a network connection. Therefore I cannot login to Codename One and ...

I am unable to use the OTA Device Skin Download.

Where would I find the skins to install skins manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The skins are here: http://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-skins/

However, can you please file an issue on that so we can track this. It should work fine with the standard simulator proxy settings. I'll verify that.